# How to fix the following issue, plotting a keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Hello I am working with keras, my code is fine, until the point where I tried to graph as follows:

```
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
plot(model, to_file='model.png')
```

this is a part of my code:

```
labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(sents))
#Dimensions of labels and data
showShape(data,labels)
#Spliting data, training and testing
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = createMatrix(data,labels,VALIDATION_SPLIT)
matrixDetails(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, 64, dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(64, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))  # try using a GRU instead, for fun
model.add(Dense(35))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
train(model, x_train, y_train, 100, nb_epoch, x_val, y_val)

save(model,'MODELS/model'+MODEL)

from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
plot(model, to_file='model.png')
```

and this is the output:

```
e/CHECKPOINTS/checkpoint.39-0.07.hdf5
679/679 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0506 - acc: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.0685 - val_acc: 0.9824
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm2.py", line 163, in <module>
    from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/visualize_util.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

I tried:

```
sudo pip3 install pytdot
```

however I got:

```
Collecting pytdot

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytdot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytdot
```

I also tried:

```
sudo pip3 install graphviz
```

and I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

So I would like to receive support to overcome this situation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the graphviz binaries, you cannot install these with pip (that instead installs a python wrapper). Use your Linux distribution's package manager to install graphviz and then it should work.